# Python: count how many times an element of a vector is in between of elements of two other vectors?

Tags: python

Say I have 3 vectors:

`v1 = 1,6,7`

`v2 = 2,5,6`

`v3 = 3,4,2`

I want to count how many times that `v1[i] <= v2[i] <= v3[i]` (in a Pythonic way of course). For the above example, the answer should be `1`.

Comment: 1) How do you compare vectors? Do you compare their length? 2) What do you mean how many times?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sum(v1[x] <= v2[x] <= v3[x] for x in range(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `v1`, `v2`, and so on are`numpy.arrays` you can do

```
np.sum(np.logical_and(v1<v2, v2<v3))
```